# Getting entity icon url in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Im CRM 2011 is it possible to get the icon url for the entity from javascript code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [query metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919080.aspx) of a entity and check the name of Web Resources that contains the [icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328173.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

This could be a function to return any icon url:

```
 function GetIconUrl (etc) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the url of the 16x16 icon for the specified entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="etc" type="Number">Entity type code of the entity which icon must be retrieved.</param>
    /// <returns type="String">Url of the icon.The path is relative to the application root.</returns>

    var url;
    if (etc >= 10000) {
        // return a custom entity icon
        url = "/_Common/icon.aspx?objectTypeCode=" + etc + "&iconType=GridIcon&inProduction=1&cache=1";
    } else {
        // return a system entity icon
        url = "/_imgs/ico_16_" + etc + ".gif";
    }
    return url;
}
```

Comment: One small addition: Not all icons are GIF, some are only available as PNG. A possible solution for this is to check for 404 errors on retrieval of the GIF image.